# QGIS generate convex hull for common attributes that have many values

Tags: qgis, convex-hull, points-to-line

If I have a points file where the points share common attributes, what's the best way to draw a convex hull around those common points using QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to select the points that share a common attribute, either manually or with the "Select by expression" icon in the attribute table window (in that case, use the expression `"yourfield" = X`, then click on "Select"):

[image]

Then, use `Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Convex hull(s)` and check the "Use only selected features" option:

[image]

This will create the convex hull you want. You have to repeat this process for each different value of the field.

Comment: What if there are many, many different values in the field? To the point where it would not be realistic to repeat the process as such

Comment: Then you'll have to use [QGIS modeler](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html) or a Python script. You should also edit your question to mention this issue.

Comment: thanks, fixed! also unfortunately I've never used the modeler or cobbled together scripts before, any tips on how I can put this together?